# Nativescript-vue: How to make a custom component tapable?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

Can I make a custom element tapable?

This is my component:

```
<template>
  <FlexboxLayout class="profile-item" flexDirection="column">
    <label :text="text" />
    <label class="subtext" v-if="subtext" :text="subtext" />
  </FlexboxLayout>
</template>
```

And this is how I would like to use it:

```
<template>
  <ScrollView>
    <StackLayout>
      <Item text="Test" @tap="onItemTap" />
      <Button text="Button" @tap="onItemTap" />
    </StackLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</template>

<script>
import Item from "./Item";

export default {
  components: {
    Item
  },
  methods: {
    onItemTap(event) {
      alert('test');
    },
  }
};
</script>
```

Taping the buttons works but not my custom element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either handle the tap event from inside the custom element or wrap the custom element inside a `ContentView` and attach the tap event to the container like this:

```html
<template>
  <ScrollView>
    <StackLayout>
      <ContentView @tap="onItemTap">
        <Item text="Test" />
      </ContentView>
      <Button text="Button" @tap="onItemTap" />
    </StackLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you. Where did you find the ContentView component? It is not documented here: https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/introduction/ . Is it possible to use ListView (https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/elements/components/list-view/) with static content?

Comment: There are some info about ContentView [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GEbUs7pf-no). I think ListView is more used for dynamic contents compared to static content.

Comment: Thank you. ContenView and tap is working fine. Clicking on a dynmaic ListView content gives a "tab" feedback on the element. Can I do this also somehow with ContentView?

Comment: I think those are the default behavior of buttons and ListView. It is possible, but you would need to create your own custom gesture handler. It's probably easier to use a ListView/button if you want that feedback.

Comment: Do you know if I can use ListView somehow with static content (not coming from an array, instead I want to write my elements directly into my template [Like my example with a Stacklayout]) ?

Comment: I don't think you can. `ListView` are more meant to work similar to a repeater where it converts the array into UI elements. You could specify different templates for different type of contents. I think to get the effect you want it would be easier to use something like the [nativescript-ripple plugin](https://github.com/edusperoni/nativescript-ripple) or [nativescript-material-ripple plugin](https://github.com/nativescript-community/ui-material-components)

Comment: I think I will create a new question about a tap feedback. Such a basic function should be possible to do without any third party app.